# Favicons on Hot Network Questions are off center

Tags: bug, design, favicon

I am seeing this on Stack Overflow, codegolf.stackoverflow.com and others (but strangely not on Meta):

[image: What?]

Is it just me or did someone push the wrong button while editing the style sheets?

Platform: Chrome 51.0.2704.103 / [Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan) (I could replicate on Safari TP, Firefox, and iOS Chrome too).

Comment: Just you, I think.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 51.0.2704.103, Windows 7.

Comment: Hmm, looks fine here. Hard-refresh the page?

Comment: I also believe you've got a high-resolution monitor? I can't repro with android.

Comment: @Adam Are the smaller or bigger sprites loading for you? Pete seems to have gotten the high-resolution images loaded, but low-res positioning was applied.

Comment: @nicael Favicon sprite was rebuilt earlier today, so my money's on the page being badly cached on Pete's end and still using the old cachebreaker.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for clarification. Maybe you should post an answer?

Comment: Same problem, [Site favicons shifted on the profile page and communities list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281486)